# 19.10, Nvidia RTX 2080, Dell UP3218K - How to start debugging Xorg monitor detection problems

Tags: nvidia, xorg, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 with an RTX 2080 Ti (Asus Strix) and Dell's 8K display (UP3218K). I installed Ubuntu Server 19.10 and then installed the ubuntu-desktop-minimal package (so, Xorg and gdm3).

This display requires two DisplayPort cables to run at full 8K (7680x4320) resolution.

If I power on the computer with one DisplayPort cable plugged in, and then plug the second one in early during the boot process (e.g., during the "press F2 to enter setup" BIOS screen), everything works perfectly. The textual part of the boot process happens in 4K (3840x2160) over one DisplayPort link, and then when Xorg starts, it detects the 8K display, switches to using the two ports, and everything works beautifully.

If I power on the computer with both cables plugged in, the textual part of the boot process happens in 8K over the two cables. When Xorg starts, I'm left at a completely black screen. (In this case, even the "press F2 to enter BIOS" screen displays at 8K over the two cables.)

**The question: I am at a loss for how to debug this. Is there a place where Xorg logs its detection so I can at least see what's going on?**

A few more details that might matter:

- This is a dual boot machine. Booting to Windows 10 with both cables connected (or just one cable connected) works completely fine. Plugging in the second cable later works fine, too.
- I've tried setting the `nomodeset` kernel option, and it makes no difference.
- I have another machine with a RTX 2070, running Ubuntu 19.04. When it boots with both cables plugged in, it only uses one cable (4K) for the textual part (including BIOS). It boots to Xorg just fine -- no problems.
- I'm using the Nvidia driver, version 435.21

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi 
Sun Nov 10 14:49:37 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:A1:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   39C    P0    64W / 260W |   2175MiB / 11016MiB |     11%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1536      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           137MiB |
|    0      1971      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           615MiB |
|    0      2181      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        1160MiB |
|    0      2463      G   ...quest-channel-token=4248222237918780630   202MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't yet know the answer to this question (how to debug such problems), and would love to know. However, I've fixed the underlying problem. It turns out secure boot (or something downstream related to secure boot) was causing the problem. Disabling secure boot in my BIOS magically fixed things.